# How access to servlet context parameters from birt javascript?

Tags: birt

I have a report with a dynamic xml file as datasource.
This file is generated previously to launch the report and is send like a report parameter.

So I declared a datasource with target in "property binding":

```
"/path_to_folder_with_generated_files/data/" + params["dynamic_xml_file"].value
```

At this point, go all right.

But i need that "/path_to_folder_with_generated_files/data/" will be

```
{BIRT_VIEWER_WORKING_FOLDER} + "/data/" + params["dynamic_xml_file"].value
```

where {BIRT_VIEWER_WORKING_FOLDER} will be the value of this context parameter declared in web.xml deploy descriptor.

How do i access to context parameters from birt javascript?

Environment: Birt 3.7.1 deployed in Glassfish 3.1, ubuntu linux, jdk 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution in: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/277462/780873/#msg_780873

```
reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getServletContext().getInitParameter("BIRT_VIEWER_WORKING_FOLDER") + "/data/" + params["dynamic_xml_file"].value
```

Thnaks, Jason.